# ios squaring edges in UIProgressView

Tags: ios, user-interface

I'm writing a UI for iPad and part of that UI needs progress bars for certain parts. However, I'm finding that configuring the UIProgressView is proving difficult. One of the requirements is that the endpoints of the progress view be square, however, I am unable to configure this via the layer's corner radius property:

```
    fProgressView = [[UIProgressView alloc] initWithProgressViewStyle:UIProgressViewStyleBar];
    fProgressView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    fProgressView.progress = 0.5f;
    fProgressView.progressImage = nil;
    fProgressView.trackImage = nil;
    fProgressView.trackTintColor = self.fPatientListPanelColor;
    fProgressView.progressTintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [fProgressView.layer setCornerRadius:1.0f];
    [self.view addSubView:fProgressView]
```

I find I am also unable to control the height of it. Any thoughts on how to overcome these issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is apparently no way to do this, so I ended up rolling my own version.